# MDX Query with Paging results

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

Can anyone give me an example of paging results(Based on page number) using MDX ?

If my question doesn't make since please ask questions.

```
Select NON EMPTY([Measure]) on Rows,
NON EMPTY([Dimension].[Members]) on Columns From [Cube Name]
```

One idea I have had is to use

```
Select NON EMPTY([Measure]) on Rows,
SUBSET(NON EMPTY([Dimension].[Members]) 1,3) on Columns From [Cube Name]
```

which would give me the second record in the result set and only three records which works as long as I don't use NON EMPTY in my SUBSET function but if I use NON EMPTY it takes forever. Any pointers in the right direction would be  appreciated

Comment: What is the purpose of paging them? That sounds like a presentation issue.

Comment: `subset(non empty` are the wrong way around to standard

Comment: ok what is the right way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micah,

See the following article.  I think this is what you are looking for.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dcb8d60d-0581-40b4-9006-4d72c02d0148/mdx-paging-using-subset-non-empty-not-working?forum=sqlanalysisservices